# How to add drop-down in each row of Material UI Table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to Use `material-ui` Drop Down Menu in each row in `material-ui` Table but when I am trying to change the value of one one drop down, the value of every drop down is changing. Here is the code :

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme)=>({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
    },
    container: {
        maxHeight: 440,
    },
    list: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    },

}));

const OrdersTable = () => {

    const classes = useStyles();
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
    const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);
    const [Data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(5);
    const [Pages, setPages] = useState(null)
    const options = [
        'PLACED',
        'ACCEPTED',
        'PREPARING',
        'FOOD READY',
        'PICKED UP',
        'DELIVERED'
    ];


    const GetData = async () => {
        const token = token
        const api = api-url
        await axios.get(api, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` } })
            .then(res => {
                const results = res.data.data.results;
                const pages = res.data.data.totalPages;
                // const statusOfOrder = res.data.data.results.orderStatus;
                setData(results);
                setPages(pages);
                console.log(results);
            })
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        GetData();
        console.log(Data.id);
        // console.log(Data.totalPages)
    }, []);

    const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setPage(newPage);
    };
    const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setRowsPerPage(+event.target.value);
        setPage(0);
    };
    const handleClickListItem = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };
    const handleMenuItemClick = (event, index) => {
        setSelectedIndex(index);
        setAnchorEl(null);
    };
    const handleClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
      };
    return (
        <Paper className={classes.root}>
            <TableContainer className={classes.container}>
                <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell align="center">Name</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="center">City</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="center">Address</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="center">Phone Number</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="center">State</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="center">Pin Code</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="center">Items</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="center">Items Count</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="center">Total Amount</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="center">Current Status</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="center">Update Status</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                        {
                            Data.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).map((row, index) => {
                                return (<TableRow key={index}>
                                    <TableCell align="center">{row.address.name}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align="center">{row.address.city}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align="center">{row.address.full_address}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align="center">{row.address.phone}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align="center">{row.address.state}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align="center">{row.address.pin_code}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align="center">{
                                        row.items.map((itemsName) => {
                                            return itemsName.name + ","
                                        })
                                    }
                                    </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align="center">{row.totalItems}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align="center">{row.grandTotal}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align="center">{row.orderStatus}</TableCell>
                                    {/* <TableCell align="center">{row.id}</TableCell> */}
                                    <TableCell>
                                        <div className={classes.list}>
                                            <List component="nav" aria-label="Device settings">
                                                <ListItem
                                                    button
                                                    aria-haspopup="true"
                                                    aria-controls="lock-menu"
                                                    aria-label="when device is locked"
                                                    onClick={handleClickListItem}
                                                >
                                                    <ListItemText primary={options[selectedIndex]} />
                                                </ListItem>
                                            </List>
                                            <Menu
                                                id="lock-menu"
                                                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                                                keepMounted
                                                open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                                                onClose={handleClose}
                                            >
                                                {options.map((option, index) => (
                                                    <MenuItem
                                                        key={option}
                                                        // disabled={index === 0}
                                                        selected={index === selectedIndex}
                                                        onClick={(event) => handleMenuItemClick(event, index)}
                                                    >
                                                        {option}
                                                    </MenuItem>
                                                ))}
                                            </Menu>
                                        </div>
                                    </TableCell>
                                </TableRow>)
                            })
                        }
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
            <TablePagination
                rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 15]}
                component="div"
                count={Data.length}
                rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                page={Data.totalPages}
                onChangePage={handleChangePage}
                onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
            />
        </Paper>
    );
}

export default OrdersTable
```

I am new to `material-ui` and react please help me or suggest me if there is some other way of doing it in efficient manner.

Comment: Could you share your data as static values without api request?

Comment: Why you want that?

Comment: I've given the static values of the column I want to update.

Comment: Actually I would like to steal your code!! Because without the data, rows doesn't display to debug the code! It's the code with a pager and nothing else!

Comment: Actually you can make your own dummy data bro...

Comment: It's your question.

Comment: Which data you want?

Comment: I try to debug your code withsample data. It seems you defined one state for all options. You should have a state which keep index of the row which has drop down and selectedIndex of the current row's option value. So you should change your selectedIndex state to an array of the objects.

Comment: Didn't got you bro can you show the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using one state for all rows which cause unforeseen events in your app, same as the one you have mentioned in your question. Something that I would like to describe applies to both `selectedIndex` and `setAnchorEl`. Anyway, You should define an array of `states` for each row's `selectedIndex` and `setAnchorEl`. In addition we should keep the current row's state when user click on the `List`. this line of code:

```
const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);
const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
```

to:

```
const [selectedIndexModel, setSelectedIndexModel] = React.useState([]);
const [currentRowIndex, setCurrentRowIndex] = React.useState(0);
const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState([]);
```

In addition there is some changes which you should apply to `handleMenuItemClick` and `handleClickListItem`.
First of all, When your rows had been added to the `Table`, you need to create a object for each row in this structure:  `{ rowIndex: index, itemIndex: 0 }` that `rowIndex` is index of each table row and `itemIndex` is the menu item in each row which had been selected. When user click on the `List` for the first time we create the object and update our state:

```
const handleClickListItem = (event, index) => {
    let copyAnchor = [...anchorEl];
    let a = copyAnchor.filter((x) => x.rowIndex == index)[0];
    if (!a) {
      a = { rowIndex: index, eventTarget: event.currentTarget };
      copyAnchor.push(a);
      setAnchorEl(copyAnchor);
    } else {
      let anchorIndex = copyAnchor.indexOf(a);
      a.eventTarget = event.currentTarget;
      copyAnchor[anchorIndex] = a;
      setAnchorEl(copyAnchor);
    }

    let copy = [...selectedIndexModel];
    let m = copy.filter((x) => x.rowIndex == index)[0];
    if (!m) {
      m = { rowIndex: index, itemIndex: 0 };
      copy.push(m);
      setSelectedIndexModel(copy);
    }
    setCurrentRowIndex(index);
  };
```

Moreover when user would like to select an menu item, we should update it based on current row, not all of the rows:

```
  const handleMenuItemClick = (event, index) => {
    let copy = [...selectedIndexModel];
    let m = copy.filter((x) => x.rowIndex == currentRowIndex)[0];
    let itemIndex = copy.indexOf(m);
    m.itemIndex = index;
    copy[itemIndex] = m;
    setSelectedIndexModel(copy);

    let copyAnchor = [...anchorEl];
    let a = copyAnchor.filter((x) => x.rowIndex == currentRowIndex)[0];
    let anchorIndex = copyAnchor.indexOf(a);
    a.eventTarget = null;
    copyAnchor[anchorIndex] = a;
    setAnchorEl(copyAnchor);
  };
```

Assume that we have a function which will render our menu items. Based on my previous description we have something like this:

```
  const renderMenuItems = (rowIndex) => {
    let m = selectedIndexModel.filter((x) => x.rowIndex == rowIndex)[0];
    return options.map((option, index) => (
      <MenuItem
        key={index}
        index={index}
        // disabled={index === 0}
        selected={m ? m.itemIndex : 0}
        onClick={(event) => handleMenuItemClick(event, index)}
      >
        {option}
      </MenuItem>
    ));
  };
```

Also we will render the menu same as this code:

```
 const renderMenu = (index) => {
    let anchor = anchorEl.filter((x) => x.rowIndex == index)[0];
    return (
      <Menu
        id="lock-menu"
        anchorEl={anchor ? anchor.eventTarget : null}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchor ? anchor.eventTarget : null)}
        onClose={(e) => handleClose(index)}
        se
      >
        {renderMenuItems(index)}
      </Menu>
    );
  };
```

At the end, we need to change the `ListItemText` and select the option for each row which had been updated:

```
  const renderListItem = (index) => {
    let selectedIndex = selectedIndexModel.filter(
      (x) => x.rowIndex == index
    )[0];
    return (
      <ListItemText
        primary={options[selectedIndex ? selectedIndex.itemIndex : 0]}
      />
    );
  };
```

[image: Edit sparkling-fog-dswkg]

Comment: There is still an issue with it it opening two lists.

Comment: @RohitArora007 I've seen that. The problem exactly because of the   `setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);` You should do the exactly thing that I've done it for the drop downs.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: @RohitArora007 I updated the answer and the link of the code. Please investigate it again.