# Multiple modal in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing a mapping for different products and each product have a "report" button. Once the button is pressed, a modal pops up and shows the relevant details of the product. But when I click on any of the "report" button, all the other modals are triggered at well. I am not retrieving the right details. It should only be on that one particular product that i clicked on. I have tried researching on here and found similar questions but still can't seem to understand. Can someone help me? This are my codes https://codesandbox.io/s/small-wildflower-o3vfy

This is my array of states:

```
    this.state = {
  reportModalShow: [false, false],
};
 let reportModalClose = (key) => {
  this.state.reportModalShow[key] = false;
};
  {this.props.custOrders.map((custOrder, key) => {
      return (
              
                  <Button
                    variant="danger"
                    style={{ marginLeft: 5 }}
                    onClick={() => {
                      console.log("Report Button Clicked");
                      let tmp = this.state.reportModalShow;
                      tmp[key] = !tmp[key];
                      this.setState({ reportModalShow: tmp });
                    }}
                  >
                    Report
                  </Button>
                  <ReportModal
                    show={this.state.reportModalShow[key]}
                    key={key}
                    onHide={reportModalClose}
                    order={custOrder}
                    orders={this.props.custOrders}
                    orderItems={this.props.custOrderItems}
                  />
                </ButtonToolbar>
```

This is my Modal:

```
  <Modal
    show={this.props.show}
    size="lg"
    aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
    centered
  >
    <Modal.Header closeButton onClick={this.props.onHide}>
      <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
        Report an Issue
      </Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
      <FormControl component="fieldset" style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
        {/* <FormLabel component="legend">Issue Type </FormLabel> */}
        <RadioGroup
          aria-label="account"
          name="account1"
          value={this.state.issueType}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        >
          <FormControlLabel
            value="missingItem"
            control={<Radio />}
            label="Missing Items"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            value="incorrectOrder"
            control={<Radio />}
            label="Incorrect Order"
          />
      
          />
        </RadioGroup>
      </FormControl>
    </Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button variant="danger"   onClick={this.props.onHide(this.props.key)}>
        Cancel
      </Button>
      <Button onClick={this.report}>Report</Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
```

Comment: hmm, perhaps there needs to be a different state for each button (`reportModalShow`)

Comment: You should use different state for each modal. So when you're rendering `ReportModal`, you assigned just one state to it. It should be an array of `states`.

Comment: does this mean i need to have create separate multiple ReportModal component?

Comment: @mathsmad No, you should change your `this.state.reportModalShow` to an array of states.

Comment: @mathsmad If you would like to know how it's working. Please share an executable sample of your code in the `condsandbox` . I will do it for you.

Comment: @MajidMohammadi alright I get that. Afterward I can set the state array to true. But how to use this on the ReportModal jsx? Sorry for asking so many questions, I am pretty new to React

Comment: When you're mapping the `this.props.custOrders` you need to find the related state from `this.state.reportModalShow` array based on current index and change  `show={this.state.reportModalShow}` to something like : `show={this.state.modalShow[index]}`

Comment: i edited my post. is that what u mean by array of states? i still cant get it to work :(

Comment: I managed to passed unique information to each modal. but my close button isnt workin g for the modal

Comment: You did not use this.setState in your on hide function and btw doing `const tmp = this.state.reportModalShow; tmp[key] = !tmp[key]` is the same as doing `this.state.reportModalShow[key] = !this.state.reportModalShow[key]`

Comment: I tried that but i keep getting this error when i use setState --> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: I couldn't debug your code in this way. If it's possible, please share an simple example of your code in codsandbox to solve your problem.

Comment: I've done something like this in the dropdown. Please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68609472/how-to-add-drop-down-in-each-row-of-material-ui-table/68620458#68620458

Comment: If I have your code, I can answer better to your questions.

Comment: this is my code https://codesandbox.io/s/small-wildflower-o3vfy  . the close button is called reportModalClose. i commented it out coz i had some errors with it

Comment: I realise that the reportModalClose is running even without even being called...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change some part of your code. First of all, when user click on `cancel` or `close` button, you need to change the current modal's state with index. It can be done with a shallow copy from `reportModalShow`:

```
  reportModalClose = (event, key) => {
    let reportModalShow = [...this.state.reportModalShow];
    reportModalShow[key] = false;
    this.setState({ ...this.state, reportModalShow }, () => {
      console.log(this.state);
    });
  };
```

Also in `onHide` event of ReportModal, you didn't send the index parameter of current modal. So you need to change it to :

```
onHide={(e) => {
     this.reportModalClose(e, key);
}}
```

At the end, change the `onClick` event of close and cancel button to in `Modal.jsx` to:

```
onClick={(event) => this.props.onHide(event)}
```

[image: Edit elastic-greider-gcxvi]